# How to execute 2 update queries in one transaction with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am new to JDBC and I am trying to update 2 tables in my database, so I would like to do it in 1 transaction so if one query fails, the other should also fail. I would like to provide such behaviour or just have an opportunity to do rollback if one of them fails.

Here are my 2 queries:

```
int i = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO product (title, price, `status`) " +
                "VALUES ( \"" + product.getTitle() + "\", " + product.getPrice() + ", " + product.getStatus().ordinal() + ");");
int j = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO product_categories (product_id, category_id) " +
                "VALUES (last_insert_id(), " + categoryId + ");");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to execute multiple statements atomically, you need to use a transaction. A JDBC connection defaults to 'auto-commit' mode, which means each statement is executed in its own transaction. So you first need to disable auto-commit mode, using [`Connection.setAutoCommit(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-).

With auto-commit mode disabled, executed statements will be executed in the current transaction, if there is no current transaction, one will be started. This transaction can then either be committed using [`Connection.commit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit--) or rolled back using [`Connection.rollback()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback--).

You will need to do something like:

```java
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(...)) {
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
        stmt.executeUpdate(<your first update>);
        stmt.executeUpdate(<your second update>);

        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

For more details, see the JDBC tutorial chapter [Using Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

And please learn about prepared statements. Concatenating values into a query string is bad, because it can lead to SQL injection or weird errors if you forget to escape values. See also the JDBC tutorial chapter [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: This line "connection.setAutoCommit(false);" should be within try catch block

Comment: Additionally, a good practice is to add "con.setAutoCommit(true);" at finally block.

Comment: @MaksymOvsianikov No, it doesn't need to, unless you want to restore the auto commit back to true. Why do you think that is required? And may I remind you that this is a simple example, not a full-fledged real-world use.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, I didn't wrote it's required, I wrote it's "a good practice" :) check this Oracle tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: This is a great answer! I think it would be good to also mention that the database needs to be set to a particular isolation level. For example, if Postgres was set to the "Read uncommitted" isolation level it would actually be possible for a query to see the inserted product before the transaction is committed, which would violate most users' expectations of atomicity.

Comment: @paulkernfeld I'll consider it, but your proposed edit suggests that if two statements are executed in a single transaction, then the changes of the first statement are already visible for read committed transactions. That is not correct, that is only possible with read uncommitted transactions, which not all databases support. I also thinks this is sufficiently covered by linking to the Oracle JDBC Tutorial.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'm not sure how to fix my proposed edit but I'm guessing that I meant to write "read uncommitted" instead of "read committed".  Overall, my goal was to come up with a simple-to-explain situation that would effectively demonstrate that the isolation level is important to satisfying an intuitive definition of atomicity. Maybe it would be enough to just mention that the database isolation level is relevant without providing an example?