# How to execute two queries atomically

Tags: java, sql, oracle

In my code, I am updating a table and based on its successful execution, I am updating a second table. I have a condition that if the second execution fails, I have to roll back the first update as well.

```
int i=update first table

if(i!=0){
 update second table
}
```

How to roll back first one when second one fails. I want both updates to be performed atomically.

Comment: put them in the **same transaction**, beside what are you using jdbc or hibernate?

Comment: What is with the hash-tags in your title? This isn't twitter..

Comment: i am not sure how to do that can you please eloborate. will anotating my method with @Transactional will do (i am using spring)

Comment: @YCF_L i am using jdbc

Comment: If you are using JDBC take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535370/5558072